# Entity Framework throwing Error 26 after creating database and tables

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

I have a solution right now that is able to create the database and tables as expected. During run-time I am able to log in (via a vanilla IdentityDbContext), however, I am receiving the following exception when trying to access the tables in a different DbContext (using the same connection string):

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"

This is really throwing me off because the application is able to connect to create the DB and Tables, query the database to log in - but is unable to access the tables after that.

**This all works locally just fine** - the error *only* shows up when deployed to an ASP.NET website hosted in MS Azure.

Allow Windows Azure Services is **enabled** in Azure for this particular deployment.

is there any particular code that would help narrow down what is causing this?

**EDIT:** I believe this post is unrelated to the one ataravati posted because I am not connecting to an attached external database, but using the same database point both locally and remotely - but only when deployed to Azure do I have any issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure website cannot access Azure DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724682/azure-website-cannot-access-azure-db)

Comment: Hi ataravati, unfortunately that question and answer seems unrelated to the issue I am having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was being caused by:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Inside the Web API. Whatever was resolving those roles was unable to connect to the database. For the time being I removed the required roles.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem between your

> DbContext constructor and your connection string

you can debugging your DbContext and you`ll find that the parameter which passed to your base class is pointing to your  local server connictionstring not to the a

Comment: Hi Shaddad, can you elaborate a bit more on your answer? Debugging locally I can see the connection string is the same for both DbContexts - I am unable to debug the Azure deployment due to no symbols found (even in debug mode)